# How to exceed max_execution_time in PHP

Tags: php, performance, time

In PHP, I want to run a script who need 2 minutes to compute but my max_execution_time is only 30 seconds.
**I can't change my max_execution_time in php.ini nor call shell_exec**

I already done all the optimization I could think of.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best" option you have is to cut your algorithm into smaller part.
Each part should execute within 30 second to avoid timeout.
Here are few ideas.

Using CURL:

- [Script Start] Call run.php let is compute for 20s.
- Save it stat into a database with an ID
- Make a CURL call run.php?resumeID=384 [Script finish]
- [Script Start] retrieve the stat and continue the computation
- and so on...

Using CRON task:

- call run.php every second. It will pick a task in your database then flag as "in progress".
  So next time run.php is call it will not pick the "in progress task"
- After 20s of computation, save the stat of your script in database and change the "in progress" flag to false.
- Next call to run.php will pick the task and continue the processing
- and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Even if you can't change the `php.ini` file itself, you might be able to change options via PHP code with [`ini_set`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

You can also try to call [`set_time_limit`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) inside your code, resetting the current time counter (this doesn't work in safe mode).

If that doesn't work, try to split the task up into multiple sub-tasks and save the temporary results, so that you can perform the task on multiple executions and thus bypass the time limit.

Comment: Same as the other comment it didn't work in my case. Probably because I'm on a share hosting(?) Yes it look like spliting the task is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set it in your .htaccess file

Add the following line to your .htaccess file

```
php_value max_execution_time 200
```

Comment: It didn't work in my case (share hosting) but nice try !

Comment: Looks like your webhost doesnt support htaccess or the mod_php is not properlly set.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try again and let you know. Don't you think this share hosting found a way to ignore max_execution_time from .htaccess ?

Answer (score 1):

Use like

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 100);`

Comment: It didn't work. Sorry I didn't mention it but I already tried